# Correct way to work out product of disjoint cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have $$a=(1\;6)(2\;5)(3\;8)(4\;7)$$
$$b=(1\;8)(2\;7)(3\;6)(4\;5)$$

I want to write $$ab$$ as a product of disjoint cycles.
This is how I do it and is it correct?
 I see that in 'a' $1\to 6$ and in 'b', $ 6 \to 3$ so I get $(1\;3)$

In 'a' $2 \to 5$ and in 'b' $5 \to 4$ so I get $(2\;4)$

In 'a'$3 \to 8$ and in 'b' $8 \to 1$ so we get $(1,3)$ but we already have this so we discard it and we look $8 \to 3$ instead.

Then we see in 'a' $8 \to 3$ and in 'b'$3 \to 6$ so we have $(8\; 6)$

Then we are left with looking at $(4\;7)$ but this will give us $(4\;2)$ which we already have so we instead look at $7\;4)$ which gives us $(5\;7)$

Is this method correct?

Comment: Usually $ab$ is to be read from right to left? So `1->8->3`, &c.

Comment: @Bernard It's done both ways. Some top-notch group theorists compose permutations from left to right. Please do not add to the OP's confusion by changing notation on him. Please compose your answers in the left-to-right style, which is apparently what his textbook uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permutation **a** sends $1 \to 6 $ and **b** sends $6 \to 3$, so **ab** sends $1 \to 3$.

Now consider where $3$ goes. **a** sends $3 \to 8$ and **b** sends $8 \to 1$, so **ab** sends $3 \to 1$. We obtain our first cycle: $(13)$

Lets see where 2 goes. **a** sends $2\to 5$ and **b** sends $5 \to 4$, so **ab** sends $2\to 4$. **ab** sends $4\to 7 \to 2$, so that we obtain our second cycle: $(24)$

Continue in this manner until you have seen where each number is sent. It is easiest to go in numeric order so you do not get confused. Keep in mind that this all depends on which direction you are composing in. For my example, I composed from left to right.

Your answer should be: $(13)(24)(57)(68)$.